# Neo4j optimization: Query for all graphs from selected to selected nodes

Tags: performance, neo4j

I am not so experienced in neo4j and have the requirement of searching for all graphs from a selection A of nodes to a selection B of nodes.

Around 600 nodes in the db with some relationships per node.

**Node properties:**

- **riskId**
- de_DE_description
- en_GB_description
- en_US_description
- impact

**Selection:**

- Selection A is determined by a property match (property: '**riskId**')
- Selection B is a known constant list of nodes (label: '**Core**')

The following query returns the result I want, but it seems a bit slow to me:

```
match p=(node)-[*]->(:Core) 
where node.riskId IN ["R47","R48","R49","R50","R51","R14","R3"]
RETURN  extract (n IN nodes(p)| [n.riskId, n.impact, n.en_GB_description] )
as `risks`, length(p)
```

This query results in 7 rows with between 1 and 4 nodes per row, so not much.

I get around **270ms or more** response time in my local environment.
I have not created any indices or done any other performance attempts.

Any hints how I can craft the query in more intelligent way or apply any performance tuning tricks?

Thank you very much,
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not yet a single label that is shared by all the nodes that have the `riskId` property, you should add such a label (say, `:Risk`) to all those nodes. For example:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE EXISTS(n.riskId)
SET n:Risk;
```

A node can have multiple labels. This alone can make your query faster, as long as you specify that node label in your query, since it would restrict scanning to only `Risk` nodes instead of all nodes.

However, you can do much better by first creating an index, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Risk(riskId);
```

After that, this slightly altered version of your query should be much faster, as it would use the index to quickly get the desired `Risk` nodes instead of scanning:

```
MATCH p=(node:Risk)-[*]->(:Core) 
WHERE node.riskId IN ["R47","R48","R49","R50","R51","R14","R3"]
RETURN
  EXTRACT(n IN nodes(p)| [n.riskId, n.impact, n.en_GB_description]) AS risks,
  LENGTH(p);
```

Comment: Cut the query time by half. Thanks